# np.random choice weighted dropout over time?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, random

I have a df where I want to show the number of people randomly added to a sports team a year where the inverse of rank is used as a normalizing weight. The code has 10 individuals to assign to a team each year. I have code for this that works fine. My problem is how can I drop teams and their weights out over time once they hit their max number of team members assigned, without dropping them from the df? I know this would require readjusting the weights and choices each year something dropped out but I'm not sure how to implement that.

- Edited to add dict

  ```
  df_dict = {'Rank1': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 3},
             'Team': {0: 'Foo', 1: 'Bar', 2: 'Baz', 3: 'Cat'},
             'current_num': {0: 6, 1: 5, 2: 9, 3: 10},
             'max_num': {0: 15, 1: 16, 2: 14, 3: 18}}


    df_input

   Rank1 Team  max_num   current_num  
     1    Foo    15          6       
     2    Bar    16          5       
     3    Baz    14          9        
     3    Cat    18          10
  ```

  df_output

  ```
   Rank1 Rank2  Team  max_num   current_num  Y1 Y2  Y3   Final_total
     1    3      Foo    15          6        4   5   4         19
     2    2      Bar    16          5        4   3   2         14
     3    1      Baz    14          9        1   2   2         14
     3    1      Cat    18          10       1   0   2         13
  ```

Current code :

```
      def Team_picker(df):
            new_weight = {1:3,3:1}
            df['Rank2'] = df.Rank1.map(new_weight)
            All_Teams = df['Team'].tolist()
            weights = df['Rank2'].tolist()
            norm = [float(i)/sum(weights) for i in weights]

            for x in range(1,4):
                 year = 'Y %d'% x
                 T = [choice(All_Teams, p=norm) for _ in range(10)]
                 Player_counts = Counter(T)
                 df[year] = df['Team'].map(Player_counts)
            T_Years = [col for col in df.columns if col.startswith('Y')]
            df['Final_Total']= df['current_num'] + (df[T_Years].sum(axis=1))

            return df
```

However, the df I'm aiming for would look more like this:

```
      df_output2

  Rank1 Rank2  Team  max_num   current_num  Y1 Y2  Y3   Final_total
   1    3      Foo    15          6         4   5   0         15
   2    2      Bar    16          5         4   3   4         16
   3    1      Baz    14          9         1   2   2         14
   3    1      Cat    18          10        1   0   4         15
```

Basically I am trying to accomplish two things 1.)stop a team from being selected or allocated a person during the draw year if they hit the ‘max_num’ so in the example Team Foo hits the max during year 2 so in year 3 they would be left out of the draw and everything would be re-weighted to accommodate. 2.) I also need to stop a ‘team’ from being allocated anymore people during that year if they reach their ‘max_num’ before all people have been assigned for the year.

Comment: Please share your df with `df.to_dict()`.

Comment: @user32185 it has been added, thanks for the reminder!